# How can I delete all files that have the same extension ".TMP"?

Tags: cmd.exe

`DEL "J:\testing.TMP"`

The above CMD command will delete a single file: `testing.TMP`. 
How can I delete all files that have the same extension `.TMP`?

Comment: `del j:\*.tmp` - use wildcards

Comment: `DEL C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\*.TMP` cannot delete the .TMP files there. Why?

Comment: @MatthewWai because the path has spaces, so it thinks Data\*.TMP is a new parameter. Use quotes to fix the issue: `del "c:\users\username\appdata\local\google\chrome\user data\*.tmp"` or alternatively, first browse to the folder, and then simply execute `del *.tmp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to first navigate to the folder in question.

For example:

```
cd /d j:\MyFolder
```

or

```
j:
cd MyFolder
```

and then execute the delete command:

```
del *.tmp
```

You can also do it all in one command:

```
del j:\MyFolder\*.tmp
```

If your folder contains spaces, you need to put the entire parameter in quotes.

Example:

```
cd /d "C:\Program Files"
```

or

```
del "F:\My Folder With Spaces\*.tmp"
```

It is good to know, that you can autocomplete foldernames by pressing Tab one or more times.

So if you type `cd /d C:\Progr` and you press tab at this point, it will change to the following 2 commands depending on how many times you press tab:

```
cd /d "C:\Program Files"
cd /d "C:\Program Files (x86)"
```

The same also works with del or any other command. Tab will autocomplete foldernames first, then continue to autocomplete filenames if it finds any.